# I get error 404 when call my api on node.js server

Tags: node.js, routes

I can't make work my simple routing on nodejs app.

I'm trying to use Moralis v2 api to connect and verify to Metamask, it gives me 404 error
Could someone help me?
This is my code

server.js

```
require("./routes/moralis.routes")(app);
```

this is moralis.routes.js inside routes folder

```
module.exports = app => {
  const moralisc = require("../moralis/moralis.controller.js");
  const router = require("express").Router();
  //request message
  router.post("/request-message", moralisc.request);
  //verify
  router.post("/sign-message", moralisc.verify);

  app.use("/api/moralis", router);
}
```

this is the moralis.controller.js inside moralis folder

```
const config = require("../config/config.js");
const MoralisDapp = require('moralis');
const Moralis = MoralisDapp.default;

exports.request = async (req, res) => {  
  if (!req.body) {
  res.status(400).send({
    res: "KO",
    msg: "No data"
  });
    return;
  }

  const address = req.body.address;
  const chain = req.body.chain;
  const network = req.body.network;
  try {
    const result = await Moralis.Auth.requestMessage({
      address,
      chain,
      network,
      domain: req.body.DOMAIN,
      statement: req.body.STATEMENT,
      uri: req.body.URI,
      expirationTime: req.body.EXPIRATION_TIME,
      timeout: req.body.TIMEOUT,      
    });

    return res.status(404).send({
      result
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

My node server runs on port 1337 and this is the Url that gives me 404 error
http://localhost:1337/api/moralis/request-message

Thanks

Comment: Place your ```app.use``` above the ```router.post('request-message'``` and see if it works

Comment: Same as before.